# Create pathway with PHP

Tags: php

What is the best way to create pathway with PHP (like [Dailymotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dailymotion))?

```
home > videos >search results for enrico macias mendiant de la amour  > macias enrico - le mendiant de l'amour
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no common answer to such a broad question.
It depends on the way you organize your site.
Usually the site structure being stored in database. So, usually such a path being built based on that information.

It is often called `breadcrumbs` and you can find some info by some googling on this term.

Answer (score 0):

I use a session for creating breadcrumbs. If user visit a page, we write in session variable a name of the page with link.

Comment: what if user opens 2 different pages in separate tabs?